# jQuery - undefined function call on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function on the click event, my collegue  defined the function as written below. Somehow I cannot access it, what is wrong?

```
function Start(data) {

this.move= function() {
  ....
};

   $('.button').click(function(){

      this.move();
    });

}
```

Comment: do you import the jquery to your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in a click function is the clicked element. Save a reference of the object in a variable outside the function and use it :

```
function Start(data) {
    var self = this; //HERE

    this.move= function() {
        ....
    };

    $('.button').click(function(){

        self.move();
    });

}
```

[Here's an article](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) that may give you more explanation about the above fix.

Answer (score 1):

try this, you must remember reference to your main function.

```
function Start(data) {
var that = this;
this.move = function() {
  ....
};

   $('.button').click(function(){

      that.move();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to keep the scope is to use [jQuery's `proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
$('.button').click($.proxy(this.move, this));
```

Comment: You beat me to it. `$.proxy` is the neater way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In an event handler bound with jQuery, `this` refers to the DOM element on which the handler was bound. See [jQuery Event Basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

You can override jQuery's `this` binding by using `function#bind` on the click handler:

```
function Start(data) {
    this.move= function() {
        ....
    };

    $('.button').click(function(){
        this.move();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Beware of browser support for `function#bind` -- if you target older browsers you'd need a polyfill or simply assign the value of `this` to another variable.